# Can one append search results in code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter

In Django, one can append query results as so: `query.filter(...).`

Does Code Igniter have similar functionality? I currently see Code Igniter's SQL querying interface as rather primitive.

Comment: As a side: If you're not interested in using CI's native Active Record have a look at [DataMapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)

Comment: sometimes primitive is more than enough to get the job done, and it doesn't have added overhead you may not need.  It's generally a good idea to not rely 100% on one thing.  Codeigniter has it's benefits one of them is it's easily extensible.

Comment: @DavidFaux: Can you be more specific as to what you're looking for? You want to append additional data to CI's Active Record `result()` object or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append results in the first place if you use UNION in you query

Comment: Thanks! I'll just use UNION in my SQL query.